# List<A> referring to a List<subclass-of-A>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, subclass, superclass

If I have a Class A that contain a List of children with class A like

```
public Class A
{
    protected List<A> children = new ArrayList<A>();
    ...
}
```

Is it then possible in a subclass B to have its own children of another class C and create a reference to the children list in class A? Class A has methods that the other classes want to use, e.g. send their children to. However, the class A is the general class, and B and C are more specific. So to make the reading of the code easier and to avoid a lot of typecasting I would like the List of the super class to refer to the List of the subclasses.

So when I update **otherChildren**, the **children** list will also be updated. I'd like to do something like in the example below, but does that not work and it can't be casted either **(children = (List< A >) otherChildren)**.

But is there anyway to achieve this? I'd really like to avoid all the typecasting I'll get otherwise.

```
public Class B extends A
{
    private List<C> otherChildren = new ArrayList<C>();

    public B()
    {
        children = otherChildren;
        ...
        // Modification of otherChildren will result in the same
        // modification in children
    }
}

public Class C extends A
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: In Java, even just using an ArrayList<T> it will automatically cast from Object to T any time you access the list.  But like djna said, it's not possible to assume that an A being added to your list is also a C without an explicit cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is change the declaration of children in class A to :

```
protected List<? extends A> children = new ArrayList<A>();
```

Comment: Oh.. I thought you would be updating only "otherChildren". Any updates on otherChildren can be viewed in children... not he other way around..

Comment: Well yeah, I am, but I had an "addMethod" in the A class as well, but I read up on some generics and saw that it was not possible if you extend like this. It did not matter much though, it was only used for testing. I'm gonna try this out and see if it works as intended.

Comment: Haven't tested it completely yet but looks good so far! Thank you for the answer!

Comment: If you want to know why this works: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that because they're different types. One of the operations you can do on an instance of `List<A>` is add an arbitrary instance of `A`; you can't do that on a `List<C>` because it's a more restricted type.

The fix is to make it so that `A` takes a type parameter:

```
public class A <T extends A> {
    protected List<T> children = new ArrayList<T>();
    // ...
}

public class B extends A<C> {
    private List<C> otherChildren = new ArrayList<C>();
    public B() {
        children = otherChildren;
    }
    // ...
}

public class C extends A<? extends A> {
    // Or some such
}
```

Of course, at that point you can also say that you don't need `otherChildren` at all. You can operate directly on `children` in the subclass and it will still all work without explicit casts.

Comment: This looks kinda promising, is there any more to it because I get loads of raw type warnings when I do this. The point of all this is like I wrote in a previous comment    "I have a bunch of methods in class A that iterate over a List of children. Class B and C also have children, but instead of implementing basically the same function in class B and C but changing the parameter type to the more specific. I would like Class B and C to use the more general one in class A." So there might actually be a better way

Comment: @Mattias: Inside A's definition, you basically change `A` to `A<T>` throughout (search-and-replace time!) Then you make B and C inherit and specialize the type through those `extends A<SomeConcreteType>` statements. At that point, any type warnings you've still got ought to be the real problems where you're Doing Something Wrong. Not enough info in your question to pinpoint those ahead of time. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

By making children refer to otherChildren you are trying to give the A a view of the `List<C>` as a `List<A>`, A could then reasonably expect to add an A object to what it thinks is a list of As, but in fact is supposed to be a collection of Cs.

This is conceptually invalid.

If this assignment is valid, then probably in C your otherChildren should be declared as as a `List<A>`. Which begs the question: why can you not use the children array directly?

edited:

I think you need a more sophisticated A, perhaps using generics with an "extend" parameter. So A doesn't have a list of As but of list of things that extend As.

Comment: I have a bunch of methods in class A that iterate over a List of children. Class B and C also have children, but instead of implementing basically the same function in class B and C but changing the parameter type to the more specific. I would like Class B and C to use the more general one in class A.

Comment: Okey, so this "extend" parameter is the same as Donal is referring to? Is there anymore to it than `public class A <T extends A>` because I get a lot of raw type warnings.

Comment: Or do you mean what Arun mentioned? Because adding an instance of A to that List does not seem to work.